# How to make a Makefile for C in VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile

I am working on a school project that has two customs made headers, each with a .c file and .h file. I like using VSCode so I copy my code into MSWord for future notes. However, it has become quite difficult to run the program with a lot of headers:

`gcc -o main.c header1.c header2.c main`

I have recently learnt of a `Makefile`, but could not find any way to create one it. I have tried reading some sites, but got quite confused. Not even sure if it would work on VSCode, or requires another extension.

Comment: There are a few good tools to automate such things for you. I recommend you try to look for some of them ([here's a list of a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software#Build_script_generation)). If you still want to create your own `Makefile` (it is a great learning exercise after all) please [edit] your question to tell us what you have tried, and what problems you have with it. And yes, you can configure VSCode to "run" a program (like `make`) for you.

Comment: For today's modern C/C++ projects, if cross platform is your goal, learn CMake which is de facto tool to go, https://cmake.org/ There are extensions for CMake already.

Comment: Why use MSWord. Much better to keep formatting is Markdown (*.md) files. And you can type them in VSC and preview them.

Comment: regarding: `gcc -o main.c header1.c header2.c main`  this is not a valid statement.  Suggest: `gcc main.c header1.c header2.c -o main` Notice the `-o` is placed just before the name of the output file.  Also this fails to enable the compiler warnings.  Suggest: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=C11 main.c header1.c header2.c -o main`

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like this:

```
main: main.o header1.o header2.o
    gcc -o main main.o header1.o header2.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<
```

Here is a good tutorial for make files: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

You can run `makedepend` to generate the dependancies for the header files.
BTW: The correct gcc command is `gcc -o main header1.c header2.c main.c`

Comment: This is actually the first Makefile tutorial that was not boring and actually showed you STEP BY STEP how it works. Thank you so much for posting it!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a variable call it `SOURCES` and assign all source files to that variable. And also for object files do the same.

#### Note that:

`$@`: refers to the target name.

`$<`: refers to the first prerequisite.

`$^`: refers to all prerequisites.

So when you execute this

```sh
make main
```

What happens is the rule is converted to be : `gcc main.o header1.o header2.o -o main` but notice that there are no object files generated.

Here `Makefile` would generate the object files according to our defined rule
which means whatever the prerequisite name, generate an object file but its extension must be `.o`.

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

#### Here is `Makefile`

```
#compiler name
cc :=gcc

#remove command
RM := rm -rf

#source files
SOURCES :=main.c header1.c header2.c

#object files
OBJS :=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

#main target
main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o main
```

Comment: regarding: `cc=gcc`  While this may work, it results in that macro being re-evaluated every time it is referenced.  Suggest: `cc := gcc`  Which still assumes that the path to the compiler executable is the first `gcc` in the `$PATH` environment variable.  better to include the path like: `cc := /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: The default value for `$(CFLAGS) is usually very restricted AND you did not include it in the compile rule.  Suggest: 1) `CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=C11`   (and place `-c` and `$(CFLAGS)` in the compile rule) and to avoid problems with `#include` files, generate a rule that creates the dependency files and include them at the bottom of the makefile. and modify the compile rule to include the dependency file that is related to the file being compiled.

Comment: regarding: `%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@` and `main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@`  Due to the ordering, the compile rule will be treated as the top level/default rule.  That WILL create problems.  Suggest placing the `main` rule first.

Comment: regarding: `SOURCES=main.c header1.c header2.c`  the use of `=` will cause this macro to be reevaluated many times.  Much better to use: `:=` so it is only evaluated once.

Comment: regarding: `rm -rf *.o main`  for various reasons, a system utility, like `rm` should be used to create a macro, near the top of the makefile, similar to: `RM := rm -rf`  then when invoking it use: `$(RM) *.o main`

Comment: with the above changes, the user can just CD to where the makefile exists, then type: `make`

Comment: @user3629249  I tried to make it very simple as possible. So the OP will understand it immediately so I didn’t include some details you suggested. Thanks so much for your suggestions, I will edit the post soon.

Comment: @user3629249 Why system utilities like `rm` should be used to created as macros?

Comment: suggest reading: [make tutorial](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/Makefile-Tutorial.html)

Comment: why use macros for utilities:  [makefile tutorial](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html)  especially the paragraph under the heading: *Example simple Makefiles for a C (or C++)*

Comment: the `make` manual contains LOTS and LOTS of details about the `make` utility.  It is a LONG read with most of it you will never use. However, [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/)

Comment: regarding your question about why creating a macro for a utility, in the `make manual`,  Suggest reading the section titled: `6.3 Variables for Specifying Commands`.  I use macros for all utilities, not just some utilities